# Bootstrap Switch Change Class to State

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-switch

How can I change some `bootstrap switch` CSS classes dynamically if the state changes to true or false? In fact, if it is possible, appending a new class also may solve my problem. Is there any simple and useful way to do it? I tampered with documentation but found nothing.

The `onSwitchChange` event is well enough for this situation but I need some help with it.

**Update**

I attached an image that tells what I want to achieve.

[image]

Comment: onSwitchChange should suffice ... what issues are you having with it ?

Comment: Assuma that the state is false, I need to change some elements border and background colors

Comment: In your switchChange callback this refers to the dom element and $(this) refers to the Jquery object. which is the input checkbox.
If you have an id attribute attached with the checkbox bootstrap-switch will automatically add a class to the bootstrap switch DOM element of the form bootstrap-switch-id-{your-checkbox's-id} , you can get that element and add remove classes to it.

Comment: OR it also has classes for bootstrap-switch-on and bootstrap-switch-off which you could work some intelligent CSS to achieve what you attached, NO JS required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think CSS is the right way to go with what you are trying to achieve,
all you need to do is enclose your switch inside a parent div and then write some CSS

```css
.parent-div .boostrap-switch-on{
  //enter styles for the ON state
  }
.parent-div .boostrap-switch-off{
  //enter styles for the OFF state
  }
```